# angular js : How to call multiple asynchronous http request one after another and store the respone for later use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please Please Help:( (disapointed)

I have a table in my mysql database that stores avalabe book times;

In my site , there are to buttons that user can hit and get the related avalable book times , which you can see in the picture attached .

[image]

Every time user hits arrow left/right , I will trigger a factory function and then I'll get a data that contains avalabe books related to that day ,Everything works fine so far.

**Problem**: 
When user first comes into my site , I'll get the current day and I'll show the avalable book times related to that day(today) , and when user hits the arrow left/right , I'll get avalabe books related to three days later from today. that works fine too.

But this is **Slow**.

I want that when user comes into my site , I get the data related to today up until two month later .

But I want to show just today's(and next day , and next 2day) avalabe books. So when user clicks on arrow left/right , I wont have to call another http request and force the user to wait until my data is avalabe to see.

Is there a way to define some asynch http requests and store the callback success data , but dont use it until user hits a special key(in my case an arrow left/right)???

Here is my http request function in a factory :

```
     app.factory('ShowBookingFacDrProfile',function($http){
         return{
             showbooking:function(scope){
                 $http.post("partials/search-drprofile/show_available_books.php",{today,nextday,next2day})// I just simplicized the object that I send here
                     .success(function(msg){
                       scope.booking=msg;;
                      //here I want to do something like this : 
                      then.post('sameURL',{next3day,next4day,next5day})
                     // I want to repeat this until 2 month later from today
                      then.post('sameURL',{next6day,next7day,next8day})

              }
         }
     });
```

related Controller:

```
    $scope.hitArrow = function(current) {
    $scope.pager = current;
    SearchFac.search($scope);
};
```

Noting special in my controller

I know that I can use promises ! , but How to store them ? where ?How to use them later  ?

I can't store them in a new scope.booking , for e.g : scope.booking2 , because then I can't use them properly :(

I cannot use cache because maybe every minute avalabe books has changed :(

This is my view:

```
   <div class='col-xs-4'>
       <table class='table table-responsive' >
           <tr data-ng-repeat='v in booking |filter:{month:date.next2month} |filter:{day:date.next2day}'>
           <td><a>{{v.hour}}</a></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>

   <div class='col-xs-4'>
       <table class='table table-responsive' >
           <tr data-ng-repeat='v in booking |filter:{month:date.nextmonth} |filter:{day:date.nextday}'>
               <td><a>{{v.hour}}</a></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>

   <div class='col-xs-4'>
       <table class='table table-responsive' >
           <tr data-ng-repeat='v in booking |filter:{month:date.today} |filter:{day:date.today}'>
               <td><a>{{v.hour}}</a></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
```

**NOTE**
Actually I've seen this approach in this site 
[Click](http://www.zocdoc.com/search/?dr_specialty=&address=&insurance_carrier=-1&refine_search=Find+a+Doctor)

Please see, and hit the arrows
you'll see how fast new avalable book times comes into the view

Comment: "I cannot use cache because maybe every minute avalabe books has changed".  If you get the available books once every minute, and store them locally, does this solve this part of the problem?

Comment: Actually I dont know a alot about caching :(
But I think in my problem , caching wont help , because if user comes first time into my site , there will be no cashed data ! And my problem still exist : Slow requests :(

Comment: maybe your work should be in you api, return and array by date, so you only make one(bigger but unique) request

Comment: Ohum , maybe , my backend is PHP , and its very simple database , 
And in a page I'll show 10 doctors with lots of avalabe books , How am I gonna do that ? :(

Comment: Agree with @bto.rdz, if performance is an issue, create an API endpoint which gets as much data as you can logically group together.  It looks like you're waiting for your first call to complete before starting your 2nd (very similar) call, etc.  Consolidate these into one call if possible.

Comment: Pleaaase check  this website to see what I exaclt want : 
http://www.zocdoc.com/search/?dr_specialty=&address=&insurance_carrier=-1&refine_search=Find+a+Doctor

Comment: If u see , in the website I mentioned , It's like the whole table is already there ! it's like there is no http requests!
all avalable times just magically appear in no time

Comment: @xe4me if you use F12 Developer tools you will see there is a new request each time you hit the arrows , so, there is not really a problem to make a request each time the arrow is clicked, the real problem is how much does the request takes, on that site each request takes between 0.5 and 3 seconds but probably, when I request for today it get today+6 days forward, so, I have enough info to show to the user and make the request if by any chance the user click the arrow again and again and again...

Comment: RolandoCC , thanks alot , I'll check .
I can do the same , but if user hits next 3 days from today , How I'm gonna use that 6days which I've got from previous hit /? 
doesn't every hit on arrows get 6days forward ? So next hit will get 6 more and more , still cannot use the 6days cached:(

Answer (score 1):

If $scope. booking is an array, you just have to append the contents of the http responses (array.push(object)).

Comment: I can't append the new data to the booking (is an array by the way) , because I connot use it , and ng-repeat sucks in over 2000 repeated data